# I want to extract zip and pass it to the method

Tags: java, inputstream, backend

Im currently dealing with Java and this is my code:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = false)
    public void kullaniciSorgulama() 
            ServisBaglanti baglanti = servisBaglantiService.getServisBaglanti(ServisEnum.EFATURA_KULLANICI_SORGULAMA, TTSKurumEnum.DOC1);
            String url1 = baglanti.getServisAdresi();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            URL url = new URL(null, url1, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream  inputStream = con.getInputStream();    
            .............
            //CODE HERE 
            ...............
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(//THE VARIABLE INSIDE THE CODE WHICH IS AN INSTANCE OF INPUT STREAM);
}
```

What is done here is that the connection is established which contains a zip file in it. What I want to do in CODE HERE part is that I want to take this zip file, unzip it and somehow convert the file to an instance of InputStream to pass the function docBuilder.parse(). But I don't want to save the zip file(or the extraction) anywhere. Could you help me please? 
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Cant see any problem here actually.
Just use default Java library `java.util.zip`.

`ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("yourFile.zip"));`
you will get `ZipInputStream` then you need to get its entry by calling 
`stream.getNextEntry();`
then you can collect entries using, for example, `Scanner`

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(stream);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        sb.append(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

The whole code:

```
public String readZip() {
        ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("yourFile.zip"));
        stream.getNextEntry();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(stream);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(sc.nextLine());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you may pass the `inputStream` itself, but I guess you want to parse a particular zipped file. For that create `zipInputStream` from `inputStream`. Move the pointer to the file (`ZipEntry`) you want to parse, and then call the `docBuilder.parse(inputStream)`.

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = ZipInputStream(inputStream);
```

Complete Code

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = false)
    public void kullaniciSorgulama() 
            ServisBaglanti baglanti = servisBaglantiService.getServisBaglanti(ServisEnum.EFATURA_KULLANICI_SORGULAMA, TTSKurumEnum.DOC1);
            String url1 = baglanti.getServisAdresi();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            URL url = new URL(null, url1, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream  inputStream = con.getInputStream();    

            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
            ZipEntry nextEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            while (nextEntry != null) {
              if(nextEntry.getName().equals("file you want to parse"))
                break;
              nextEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
            }

            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);
}
```

Please replace `file you want to parse` to the file name/path you want to parse

Comment: the point is, ZipEntries are being iterated, and we are moving the pointer to the appropriate ZipEntry. For example say you have a Zip file which has (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt) and you want to parse b.txt , but if you give the inputStream as it is it will start with a.txt and not b.txt